# Custom command to be executed even if preceding command fails

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

end command gets executed even if a preceding command fails. E.g. `browser.waitForElementIsVisible("non-existing-item", 500).end()`

I need to write a custom command that gets called always same as end command. If I try `browser.waitForElementIsVisible("non-existing-item", 500).saveVideo().end()` or `browser.waitForElementIsVisible("non-existing-item", 500).saveVideoAndEnd()` the command does not get called if prev command fails.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks
Tomas

Answer (score 0):

I think it might just be the way you are writing your custom command. `.end()` is not a function that your `saveVideo()` custom command is aware of, so instead, do something like this. (You don't give a lot of information in terms of your function but the below should work with a few tweaks specific to needs)

```
let saveVideoAndEnd = require ('../saveVideo.js');
this.myTest = (browser) => {
  saveVideo(browser).end( /* Callback Function */ )
}
```

Chain more nightwatch functions calls below if needed. Adjust to your needs.

```
// saveVideo.js - or amend from module export to function declaration if same file
module.exports = (client) => {
  client
    .waitForElementIsVisible("non-existing-item", 500)
    .saveVideo() 
}

function saveVideo() {
  // fn: logic
}
```

Comment: I don't get the code.
saveVideo does not get called if wait for "non-existing-item" fails - the item not found.

Comment: @T.Vojtech Then you need to do the `.end()` on the back off `.wairForEelementVisible` ? What exactly are you asking?